# How to add more to this query

Tags: sql

I wrote the query below that gets me the daily costs of specific account codes if they exist. However, I need to add in another account code but I only want it to be included if it appears on the same date as the other account codes. I am not really sure how to accomplish this. I can't add it to the WHERE because I still want it to bring back the other costs regardless of whether or not this new account code exists or not. I am currently trying my hand at a subquery

```
SELECT Distinct
  DailyCosts.WellID, DailyCosts.JobID,CasingInfo.HoleSection,
  CasingInfo.ShoeDepth, 
  SUM(DailyCosts.DailyCost) OVER(Partition by DailyCosts.WellID 
    Order by DailyCosts.WellID) As SurfaceCosts
FROM DailyCosts 
JOIN CasingInfo ON DailyCosts.WellID = CasingInfo.WellID
WHERE (AccountCode ='10670' 
    OR AccountCode ='10680'
    OR AccountCode = '10202'
    OR AccountCode = '10203') 
  AND (DailyCost <> .0001 
  AND DailyCost <> 0.001 
  AND DailyCost <> 0.00 
  AND DailyCost <> .002 
  AND DailyCost <> 0.01 
  AND DailyCost <> 1) 
  AND (HoleSection = 'surf') 
ORDER BY WellID, SurfaceCosts
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

So, you are missing alot of info in your question, but here is something to get you started.

first I advise you to format the query to make it more readable.

```
Select Distinct
    DailyCosts.WellID, 
    DailyCosts.JobID,
    CasingInfo.HoleSection,
    CasingInfo.ShoeDepth, 
    SUM(DailyCosts.DailyCost) 
    OVER (Partition by DailyCosts.WellID Order by DailyCosts.WellID) As SurfaceCosts
From DailyCosts 
    JOIN CasingInfo 
        ON DailyCosts.WellID = CasingInfo.WellID
Where   
    AccountCode IN('10670' , '10680' , '10202' , '10203') AND 
    DailyCost NOT IN (0.0001 , 0.001 , 0.00 ,0.002 , 0.01 , 1) AND 
    HoleSection = 'surf' 
Order by WellID, SurfaceCosts
```

Second, notice the replaced Multi-OR / Multi-AND logic with IN clause, shorter and prettier.

Last -> "I only want it to be included if it appears on the same date as the other account codes"
You didnt provide any reference to dates in your example (no column / no schema) but assuming its in one of joined tables
you should be able to filter this using another condition in the WHERE clasue, you try a case when expression
something like:

```
AND case when AccountCode = '<the additional account code>' and <date date_column> in (select <date_column> from table where AccountCode in (<existing accounts>))...
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: So I may need you to help a little more: This is what I added but now I'm getting syntax errors. Case When AccountCode = '10521' and DailyCosts.ReportNo in (select DailyCosts.ReportNo  from DailyCosts where AccountCode in ('10680'))